# Getting frequent XSS warnings from Firefox

Tags: firefox, noscript, xss

With the recent changes to Firefox (and NoScript apparently) I am getting frequent XSS warnings from "tqn" in particular. It seems to happen every time I do even minor things like open a new tab in Firefox. This is what it looks like:

[image]

Can somebody help parse this error and explain to me why it is happening?

Comment: I am getting similar warnings for tidal.com (which I visited once). Always allow doesn't stop the popups

Comment: It did something like this for me from the search bar, the first time I searched for a Wikipedia entry. I suppose it is a cross-script to load something, maybe even just the favicon. My guess is that You might get more eyes on this question on the NoScript support forum. https://forums.informaction.com/viewforum.php?f=7

Comment: Did you solve it? I had the same, but it stopped. I wish I knew why and what's tqn in the first place

Comment: @fedes. Nope still happening and getting worse.

Comment: According to FF Lightbeam in my case it seems it's some kind of favicon request from lifewire.com

Answer (score 1):

My partial results:

whois.com says tqn.com is registered to MarkMonitor Inc., that has a markmonitor.com site.

In markmonitor.com says Mark Monitor Inc. is some company selling intellectual property protection related stuff.

The request in my case came from a favicon request for a lifewire.com page. Revisiting that page triggered the NoScript warning again.

I don't know why a favicon request would trigger an XSS warning though, so this is not a complete answer. I put this here in case it's useful to someone.

Maybe some kind of fingerprinting going on?

Answer (score 0):

These urls are generated with [thumbor](https://github.com/thumbor/thumbor/). You can apply filter on some images via thumbor.
In your example, a [fill filter](https://thumbor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/filling.html) is applied. Thumbor filter uses parenthesis.
Parenthesis are valid characters in URI (see [RFC 3986 - Section 2: Characters](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2)).

IMO the problem is No-Script extension which is too restrictive. You should report the problem to No-Script communauty.